# Cannot resolve symbol 'context'

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to write an Android app which automatically uploads a picture to a server, but I am stuck on just one line of code:

```
        File f = File(context.getCacheDir(), "filename");
```

The error I get is 
[image]

This puzzles me because I see so many examples on the web of people using `context.getCacheDir()` just fine, whereas I get the error message.
It's probably something wrong with my IDE settings. I am using IntelliJ IDE.

Here's is the context of the context problem:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
        {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCaptured);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            //create a file to write bitmap data
            File f = File(context.getCacheDir(), "filename");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: What super class does UploadToServer have?

Comment: Do you pass **context** anywhere? or somehow get it?

Comment: Is this code in an Activity?  Where is `context` defined and initialised?

Comment: There's no variable named `context` in the scope. There's too little context (sic) in the question to tell how to resolve it. Expecting people to download zips just to answer questions is not realistic.

Comment: You have to use `getBaseContext()` or `getAppicationCOntext()` instead of `context`

Comment: I won't download a zipped file to analyze it, as Iaalto pointed out.

Comment: ok I'll post the source code in the question

Comment: Post only the relevant code

Comment: I expected context to already be provided by Android. How can I make context?

Comment: File f = File(getCacheDir(), "filename");

Comment: @RajeshCP `File f = File(getCacheDir(), "filename");` doesn't work

Comment: the use  File f = File(getAppicationCOntext().getCacheDir(), "filename");

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to do some basic Java programming tutorials.  Java is totally different to JavaScript.

Here, you use `context` as a variable but you have neither declared it, or initialised it, hence the error.

You could define it (and initialise at the same time)

```
 Context context = this;
```

since `this` refers to the current object instance of a class and `Activity` is a `Context`, or more precisely, it `extends` `Context`.

Alternatively, you could just use `this`.

```
File f = File(UploadToServer.this.getCacheDir(), "filename");
```

Comment: When I use `File f = File(this.getCacheDir(), "filename");` I get 'Method call expected' error

Comment: I solved 'Method call expected' by adding new : `new File f = File(this.getCacheDir(), "filename");`

Answer (score 6):

The error is bacuse you havent declared `context`, neither it has been passed as a parameter

change `context.getCacheDir()` to `getApplicationContext.getCacheDir()` or `this.getCacheDir()`

so

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
    {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCaptured);
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        //create a file to write bitmap data
        File f = File(context.getCacheDir(), "filename");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

will become

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
    {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCaptured);
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        //create a file to write bitmap data
        File f = File(getApplicationContext.getCacheDir(), "filename");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
Context context = this;
```

You need this to initialize context

Then Alt+Enter

You must assign context to this Activity